# Problems signing with Crypto.signWithCertificate()

Tags: apex, integration, encryption, crypto

I am trying to connect with an external service, which in its documentation asks me to generate a CMS from an XML and a certificate and private key with openssl :
[image]
[image]

In salesforce use "Certificate and Key Management" to generate my certificate and private key, then sign it in the external service and upload it back to salesforce :
[image]

In my code I am using the Crypto.signWithCertificate() method to try to replicate what requests the documentation from the external service, but the output of the base 64 signature is very different from what openssl gives me, and the service responds with a bad.cms :
[image]
[image]

If anyone can have a solution to my problem it would be a great help.
I leave attached an example that the documentation provides in java.
Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: [CMS and S/MIME](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ERAbwqs5y8EJ:https://cse.buffalo.edu/DBGROUP/nachi/ecopres/yiwen.ppt&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) is not just a signature or a straightforward application of an encryption primitive. Your best way forward is to use an existing security library and integrate it with Salesforce through one of the available platform methods. For example,  [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) handles CMS and you can write a JavaScript component that runs on Salesforce or runs elsewhere and talks to Salesforce via APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will try to apply your advice